Symfony use direct value in Environment Variable Processor
In documentation it says to define 2 YAML parameters for Environment Variable Processor to work:
parameters:
    env(FOO): 'file.json'
    app.file: '%env(file:FOO)%'

Is it possible to use file name directly? E.g.:
parameters:
    app.file: '%env(file:"file.json")%'


Yes, you can use the file name directly as you already described.
parameters:
    app.file: '%env(file:"file.json")%'

The notation, that you described first ensures, that the env variable FOO is always present to Symfony, even it is not set in the environment.
There is an explanation in the Symfony docs

If your application tries to use an env var that hasn't been defined, you'll see an exception. You can prevent that by defining a default value for the env var. To do so, define a parameter with the same name as the env var using this syntax:

parameters:
    # if the FOO env var value is not defined anywhere, Symfony uses the value 'file.json'
    env(FOO): 'file.json'
    app.file: '%env(file:FOO)%'

